# http request data and elements where this data is taken

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, google-chrome-extension, fetch

thank you for help!
I code a chrome extension and
I need that when the user sends data I have this data and the elements from which the data is taken, with which this can be implemented?

I need to get the data that is sent by an http request and from which element this data is taken. How can I implement this?